# Detecting loss of connection to fix gateway? (QuickFix)

Tags: c++, sockets, connectivity, quickfix, fix-protocol

I'm trying to find a good way to detect a loss of connection.

My adapter is implemented as a Fix::Application based on one of the examples. It uses a socket initiator to connect to the fix gateway.

When I unplug the internet it takes about 30 seconds for the Fix::Application's onLogout method to be fired. It seems like some underlying class would be aware that there is a problem with the socket much earlier. Is there a quick way took hook into this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to solve this would probably be to decrease your Heartbeat Interval so you know sooner. I don't know of any messages that fire for a loss of TCP connection, but I don't think QuickFix is listening for OS events either. Although, it would likely flow through the fromAdmin event if there were such a message.

Did you post your question to the QuickFix DL?

Answer (score 3):

It's possible that the fix engine you're using doesn't call back when TCP is disconnected, or it calls back on something other than onLogout.
Since you're using fix, I would guess it forces a logout due to missed heartbeats.

Quick way would be to look into the code and check where socket close is being handled, and what path executes when this happens.

Comment: Yeah, QuickFIX doesn't handle all socket errors well (even when establishing a new connection).